# How to update HP bios for Z840 including utilities and driver packs

Tags: drivers, updates, uefi, hp, bios

I found directions on how to update my bios on this site by creating a usb and flashing the hp bios.bin file.  However there are a number of other updates available on the HP site which I am not sure how I can update.  These files include:

BIOS Utilities for Linux
Intel Management Engine (9.1) Firmware Update and Utilities for Linux
HP Flash and Replicated Setup Utilities for Linux

I would like to install these files to complete my system update does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: The ones I downloaded like `sp90103.tgz` contain a tar file, which when unpacked contains a README file which details how to upgrade that BIOS/firmware. There's a LINUX64 binary in the package along with the documents. Do the others not have this documentation?

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; my recent firmware updates have been normal upgrade notifications during OS upgrades (*dell & not HP hardware though; only annoying thing is they required reboot*)

Comment: @popey thank you the README was helpful for most of the files.